# I made an app which crashes and I can't see any reason for that

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialogflow-es

I recently made an app with Android Studio in which I integrated the Dialogflow API.
My code is error free, but, the app is crashing as I run it on the emulator.

I'm running :

- Android Studio 3.1.3
- Gradle Version : 4.4
- Android Plugin Version : 3.1.3
- Emulator : Nexus 5X API-26

**My Project Level Gradle File :**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

**My App's Gradle File :**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.therationalbloke.myzen"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**My MainActivity.java Code :**

```
package com.testfile.dialogf;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ai.api.AIListener;
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.AIService;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Result;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener {
    AIService aiService;
    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            makeRequest();
        }
        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN",
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
        AIService aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
        aiService.setListener(this);
    }

    protected void makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                101);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101: {

                if (grantResults.length == 0
                        || grantResults[0] !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void buttonClicked (View view){
        aiService.startListening();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(AIResponse result) {
        Log.d("ZenR", result.toString());
        Result result1 = result.getResult();
        t.setText("Query "+result1.getResolvedQuery()+" action: "+result1.getAction());




    }


    @Override
    public void onError(AIError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningCanceled() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onListeningFinished() {

    }
}
```

Now, when I'm running this code on my emulator. The app is crashing. There are no errors in the syntax whatsoever. I'm not really sure what this is about.

[Here's the error on my emulator as app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRMG.jpg)

Comment: Share the error log please.

Comment: You did not show an error in your screen shot

Comment: @tahsinRupam
There are no errors actually. The build has finished perfectly fine. The code shows no error. Just when I run the app on my emulator, it states, "App stopped working".
There are no errors in my error log. Just my app is crashing.

Yes, I can show you my LogCat if you want.
Here's the link to that :
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=44810318685923272844

Comment: The warning message in the bottom left of the screen shot says that the software running on the emulator doesn't match your source code. You might want to clean, rebuild, and re-launch your app first before trying to debug. The logcat should show the cause of the crash.

Comment: Here is your error - _java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ai.api.android.AIService.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at com.therationalbloke.myzen.MainActivity.buttonClicked(MainActivity.java:69)_

Comment: @TedHopp Here's the link to my Error Log :

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02484434172024641680

Comment: @tahsinRupam What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: @thelostorbital check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already declared `aiService` globally:

```
AIService aiService;
```

No need to declare inside `onCreate()` again. **Replace the following line**:

```
AIService aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
```

**With:**

```
aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
```

Comment: One more thing. I get this prompt as I run the code :
http://prntscr.com/k2rhl6

Moreover, as I made this change, the "Listen" button is now unresponsive.
I click on the button, and nothing happens.

Here's what I see in the ERROR Logcat when I press "Listen" Button :
07-05 13:27:05.655 14259-14648/com.therationalbloke.myzen E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)

Comment: Set `onClickListener` to your button programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for an app to crash can be Compile-Time Errors or Run-Time Errors.

Compile-Time Errors can be syntax errors , class not found errors, overloading errors which are shown and recorded by the Android Studio. In your case there would be no Compile time errors since your app is correctly getting compiled and installed on the device.

Run- Time errors occur when you are using (running) the app. They are mostly logical errors or variable declaration errors. In your case may be the problem lies here only.

When you are running the app the codes are being executed and the logic is also executed. Thus if you have given some wrong logic in your code such as infinite loop, passing string instead of integer data type and many more then the app is getting crashed.

You must check the Log to see what is the exception which caused the crash. In the log (lower part of the IDE) there will be the name of the Exception, the element which launched it and also there will be the links to the lines of the code where the problem was found.

If you still can't find the error this way, you can set breakpoints at the left of the lines of code where you want the application stops during debug, and then run the app in the debug mode to see exactly what happens.

Another tip: often, when I was sure about the rightness of my code and it runs but crashes, it's about having declared all the Activities in the manifest (or all the Services) and to have set all required permission. Because in this case there are no apparent errors before running the app.